# Создание файла gitignore

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, git, gitignore

Создаю один маленький проект, который необходимо залить на Bitbucket. Проект - Классическое приложение Window - WPF, .Net.

Появился вопрос: как правильно создать файл .gitignore, чтобы туда не входили лишние файлы (типа папок Debug, Release и т.п.). Чтобы остались только те файлы, которые бы я смог запустить на другом компе в VS и получить готовый .exe файл.

Может быть подскажете ещё какие-нибудь плюшки в этом деле? Может не стоит ещё что-то загружать?

Comment: [VisualStudio.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)?

Answer (score -1):

Создаем файл .gitignore и добавляете каталог для исключения:

```
cmd> git config core.excludesfile <catalog>
```

И ислючаем файлы:

```
cmd> git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

[Ignore file changes with Git](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/ignore-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Это ответ на какой вопрос?

Comment: Автор спрашивал не как создать файл на диске, а что должно входить в список игнорируемых файлов под конкретный тип проекта.

Comment: @PashaPash, так список формипруется в зависимости от требований проекта.

Comment: @Yaroslav ну да, так это и был вопрос про типовые требования конкретного вида проекта. И про файл .gitignore в одном репозитории.  А ваш ответ к этому никакого отношения не имеет (включая все команды в нем - они не создают .gitignore, и не добавляют в него исключения)

Comment: @PashaPash, я просто думаю если добавить запись .gitignore так же как и без нее))))